# Complete this logo project in Python turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have been trying to design the below image using Python turtle graphics.

[image]

So far, this is what I have come up with.

[image]

Here is my code snippet.

```
from turtle import Turtle
t=Turtle()
t.hideturtle()
t.speed(0)

def text():
    t.color("blue")
    t.write("AOL",align="center",font=("Adobe Gothic Std B",100,"bold"))

def circle_with_color_fill():
    t.up()
    t.setpos(200,50)
    t.down()
    t.color("blue")
    t.begin_fill()
    t.circle(40)
    t.end_fill()

def circle():
    t.up()
    t.setpos(200,40)
    t.down()
    t.color("blue")
    t.circle(50)

text()
circle_with_color_fill()
circle()
t.screen.mainloop()
```

Can anyone suggest how I can get those triangles?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the text worked out, here's a rough approximation of the logo using *stamping*:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

STAMP_UNIT = 20

screen = Screen()

aol = Turtle(shape='triangle', visible=False)
aol.color('blue')
aol.turtlesize(140 / STAMP_UNIT)
aol.stamp()

aol.shape('circle')
aol.turtlesize(80 / STAMP_UNIT, outline=12)
aol.color(screen.bgcolor(), 'blue')
aol.stamp()

screen.exitonclick()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]